# Does DocuSign support ADFS 3.0 for enabling SSO?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking into the features of DocuSign, but in the [DocuSign SSO documentation](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/single-sign-on-implementation-guide) there is nothing about ADFS 3.0.

I did find a [support article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/SSO-v2-URL-Identity-Provider-Settings) which suggests some support for it though.

Can anyone give me a clear answer?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the answer is yes. Contact your DocuSign technical sales or support person for the details.